# Pull up and pull down on same circuit? LTC-2950-1 and AP2112K

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

Taken my first steps using IC's and getting a PCB made up but  all very new so solution may be something simple I am missing. My current issue is using the LTC2950-1 ([Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/295012fd.pdf)) to control a pushbutton and power on an AP2112K-3.3 LDO ([Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2112.pdf)).

The enable pin from the LTC2950 is connected directly enable pin on the AP2112K. The enable pin is expecting a high input to turn on (min 1.5v) and has an internal 3M pull-down resistor.

The LTC2950-1 enable outputs high (Cannot find in the datasheet what voltage that is) when the button is pressed but I cannot see this happening (Cheap multimeter testing voltage between EN and GND pin on LTC2950). Reading the datasheet (After I already had PCB's) I saw that LTC2950 EN pin wants the LDO to have an internal pull-up or else add an external pull-up to VIN. With a 10K resistor in place between the AP2112K EN and VIN the LDO turns on as I would expect but makes the LTC2950 useless.

I feel like I am mis-understanding how the LTC2950 is functioning but cannot figure out exactly what I am missing.

Questions

1. What am I doing wrong for this to not be working?
2. Is it possible to fix this circuit by hand?

Basic Example circuit below to hopefully make the explanation above more clear
[image: Basic Example Circuit]

Comment: there is no button switch in your schematic

Comment: what does this mean? ... `fix this circuit by hand`

Comment: So, you have an active LO output (actually, an open-drain output that is active LO and inactive when HI) that is tied to an active HI input. That seems to be a fundamental conflict, if I'm understanding you. If you don't add a resistor, then the AP211K's own internal pulldown keeps the line itself weakly LO, which the LTC2950 doesn't mind or care about. And when the LTC2950 goes active, all it does is.. well ... pull the line LO. So nothing happens. And if you add the resistor pullup externally, then the AP2112K is ON even when the LTC2950 is inactive. Sounds like a problem for a BJT to me.

Comment: Are you certain you got the LTC2650-1, or did you get the LTC2650-2? They're identical except where one asserts enable high, the other asserts enable low.